# При нажатии кнопки home вызывается surfaceDestroyed или нет?

Tags: android

Привет. При нажатии кнопки home вызывается surfaceDestroyed или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Если SurfaceView находится в текущей Activity, то нет. Она уничтожится позже, когда система решит, что эта Activity больше не понадобится.